# Count number of rows

Tags: php

Hello this here is my code

```
$query['2'] = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT site FROM logs") or die(mysql_error());

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query['2'])) {
    if (!$row['site'] == NULL) {
        echo "<a href='http://".$row["site"]."' target='_BLANK'>".$row["site"]."</a>  <a href='./" . basename($_SERVER[PHP_SELF]) . "?site=" . $row["site"] . "'> (View logs)</a>
        <a href='./" . basename($_SERVER[PHP_SELF]) . "?action=exportall&site=" . $row['site'] . "'>(Dump to file)</a>
        <a href='./" . basename($_SERVER[PHP_SELF]) . "?action=delete&site=" . $row['site'] . "'>(Delete)</a>
        <br>";
    }
}
```

This gives the output of

> test.com (View logs) (Dump to file) (Delete)

I would like it to be this

> www.iraceonline.com (View logs) (Dump to file) (Delete) (26 rows)

Some how by adding a code like this into the code above
`mysql_num_rows(mysql_query()`

It's a hard question to ask. but I think some would understand.

**------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------**

### **QUESTION HAS BEEN SOLVED! - Thanks everyone for trying to help me!**

The code needed was this below I figured it out with some simple common sense.

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query['2'])) {
    if (!$row['site'] == NULL) {
        $numSites = $row['site'];
        echo "<a href='http://".$row["site"]."' target='_BLANK'>".$row["site"]."</a>  <a href='./" . basename($_SERVER[PHP_SELF]) . "?site=" . $row["site"] . "'> (View logs)</a>
        <a href='./" . basename($_SERVER[PHP_SELF]) . "?action=exportall&site=" . $row['site'] . "'>(Dump to file)</a>
        <a href='./" . basename($_SERVER[PHP_SELF]) . "?action=delete&site=" . $row['site'] . "'>(Delete)</a>
        (".mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT site FROM logs WHERE site='$numSites'")).")
        <br>";
    }
}
```

So it was this here -

```
mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT site FROM logs WHERE site='$numSites'"))
```

Comment: `mysql_num_rows($query['2'])`

Answer (score 4):

```
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($query['2']);
```

That should get you what you're looking for.

Comment: That would not work.But I did find it it's like this-$numSites = $row['site'];mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT site FROM logs WHERE site='$numSites'")):) thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **mysql_num_rows($query['2'])** to get the count of rows.

Comment: Used this instead-

    $numSites = $row['site'];
    mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT site FROM logs WHERE site='$numSites'"))

thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

You could change your SQL query to this:

```
mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS num_rows, site FROM logs WHERE 1 GROUP BY site")
```

Then the number of rows for each site in your loop will be in $row['num_rows']

Comment: This code worked fine here-

    $numSites = $row['site'];
    mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT site FROM logs WHERE site='$numSites'"))

Comment: Yes, your code would work. However, if you have any decent amount of sites returned your performance is going to go down the drain fast because you are doing an extra SQL query for EVERY site in your loop. IMHO it would be better to have MySQL do the heavy lifting with just one query per my solution.